# Android - Cannot Access SharedPreferences Booleans - Nothing Appears In LogCat

Tags: sharedpreferences

I've implemented an instance of shared preferences using the following method:

STARTPOINT:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("name",true);
        editor.putBoolean("cap",true);
        editor.putBoolean("code",true);
        editor.putBoolean("time",true);
        editor.putBoolean("ssid",true);
        editor.commit();
```

ENDPOINT:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
            boolean name = prefs.getBoolean("name", true); 
            boolean cap= prefs.getBoolean("cap", true);
            boolean code = prefs.getBoolean("code", true);
            boolean time = prefs.getBoolean("time", true);
            boolean ssid = prefs.getBoolean("ssid", true);
```

TEST METHOD:

```
Boolean isTrue;
                isTrue = null; // valid
                isTrue = true; // valid
                isTrue = false; // valid
                if (isTrue == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Working Boolean!!!");
```

and

```
Boolean isTrue;
            isTrue = null; // valid
            isTrue = true; // valid
            isTrue = false; // valid
            if (isTrue != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "NON Working Boolean!!!");
```

RESULT:

Nothing Appears In LogCat using either method

QUESTION:

Did I implement everything correctly? If so - why can't I null check my new shared preferences?

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean name = prefs.getBoolean("name", true);
    boolean cap= prefs.getBoolean("cap", true);
    .....

Comment: How can I null check it to ensure the data is there? A standard null check does not seem to work.

Comment: I'm trying to use both Boolean isTrue;
             isTrue = null; // valid
             isTrue = true; // valid
             isTrue = false; // valid
             if (isTrue == null) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Working Boolean!!!");


and 
Boolean isTrue;
             isTrue = null; // valid
             isTrue = true; // valid
             isTrue = false; // valid
             if (isTrue != null) {
              Log.d(TAG, "Working Boolean!!!");


NEITHER are showing up in my LogCat

Answer (score 0):

I have try below code and guess what its show in logcat "val if null"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("name", true);

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",0);
// Boolean val=prefs.getBoolean("name1", true);
Boolean  val=null;
//Log.e("vaaa00", ""+val.toString());
if(val!= null)
   Log.e("val if ", ""+val);
else
   Log.e("val else", ""+val);        
}
```